# Problem with jq doing a select and contains

Tags: jq

I have limited experience with jq and am having an issue doing a a select contains for a string in a boolean.  This is my json and am looking to get back just tdonn.

```json
[
  "user",
  "admin"
]
[
  [
    "tdonn",
    true
  ]
]
```

Here is what im trying. I have tried many different ways too.

```
jq -e -r '.results[] | .series[] | select(.values[] | contains("tdon"))[]'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a small snippet of JSON that is illustrative, together with a short description of your requirements. You might find the [mcve] guidelines helpful.

Comment: {
  "results": [
    {
      "statement_id": 0,
      "series": [
        {
          "columns": [
            "user",
            "admin"
          ],
          "values": [
            [
              "tdonn",
              true
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the sample JSON shown in a comment, the following filter would produce the result shown:

```
.results[] | .series[][] | flatten[] | select(contains("tdon")?)
```

### Output with -r option

```
tdonn
```

Answer (score 1):

You might like to consider:

```
jq '.. | strings | select(contains("tdon"))'
```

Comment: this is the full json.  {
  "results": [
    {
      "statement_id": 0,
      "series": [
        {
          "columns": [
            "user",
            "admin"
          ],
          "values": [
            [
              "tdonn",
              true
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: i wasnt able to get the results with what you proposed

Comment: 1. The JSON should be part of the Q.  2. If you're using a Windows shell, you'd have to quote the command-line arguments appropriately, or use the -f option.